# how to reduce the number of sub queries in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to optimize/reduce the sub query:

```
select cash from INFO where cid IN (
    select tid from activity where point='aaa' and stats='bbb' and tid IN (
        select rid from request where stats in ('vvv','ddd') and TS >= to date ('2022-05-04','YYYY-DD-MM')))
```

Comment: Why do you want to reduce the number of subqueries? When Oracle sees `in` or `exists` it understands that you need to check the presence of some value and do not actually care about the number of cases. That's why it may use different and optimal query plan compared to the more readable join. If you have any issue with an execution time, then please provide current *actual* execution plan (by executing `select * from dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format => 'ALL ALLSTATS LAST')` in the same session right after your query had finished)

Comment: @astentx this is actually in prod and when i try to execute this i get user has no select privilege on V$SESSION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to do anything as the query is optimised as it is and sub-queries are not always things to get rid of.

---

If you change the query to use `JOIN`s then it is likely that you will get different results as the `JOIN`ed query can then return duplicate rows where previously you would have only got unique rows.

For example, if you have the data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE info (cash, cid PRIMARY KEY) AS
SELECT 100, 1 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE activity (id PRIMARY KEY, tid, point, stats) AS
SELECT 2, 1, 'aaa', 'bbb' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE request (id PRIMARY KEY, rid, ts, stats) AS
SELECT 3, 1, DATE '2022-04-05', 'vvv' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 1, DATE '2022-04-06', 'ddd' FROM DUAL;
```

Then your query:

```sql
SELECT cash
FROM   INFO
WHERE  cid IN (
         SELECT tid
         FROM   activity
         WHERE  point='aaa'
         AND    stats='bbb'
         AND    tid IN (
                  SELECT rid
                  FROM   request
                  WHERE  stats in ('vvv','ddd')
                  AND    TS >= DATE '2022-04-05'
                )
       );
```

Outputs:

> | CASH |
> | --- |
> | 100 |

But if you use `JOIN`s:

```sql
SELECT i.cash
FROM   info i
       JOIN activity a ON a.tid = i.cid
       JOIN request r ON r.rid = a.tid
WHERE  a.point = 'aaa'
AND    a.stats = 'bbb'
AND    r.stats IN ('vvv', 'ddd')
AND    r.ts >= DATE '2022-04-05'
```

Then the output is:

> | CASH |
> | --- |
> | 100 |
> | 100 |

As one row from `cash` was joined to one row from `activity` which was joined to two rows from `request` and both rows are returned.

---

You may have got rid of the sub-queries but you get a different output!

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=3c581e8672b0a48e01492b8602b5f9d5)*

Answer (score 0):

Joins, I guess.

```
SELECT i.cash
  FROM info i
       JOIN activity a ON a.tid = i.cid
       JOIN request r ON r.rid = a.tid
 WHERE     a.point = 'aaa'
       AND a.stats = 'bbb'
       AND r.stats IN ('vvv', 'ddd')
       AND r.ts >= DATE '2022-04-05'
```